# Change css of host from within a component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm just playing around with an idea of having my bootstrap 3 login page use a unique background image in my Angular 5 app. The goal is to change the body css for the index.html page, but only when the login page is loaded.

I couldn't get an image loaded so I reverted to the simplest idea I could think of -simply set the color and see if I could get that to work.

login.component.css

```
:host(.body){
    background-color: green;
}    

.form-control { height:100px}
```

I know that the file is being reference b/c the .form-control css changes my textinput to 100px. But the body of the page won't change. I tried passing (.body) (body) and even () body.  Nor do :host-context() variations work.

Then I tried this within the component like so, with no success:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    host:     {'body':'background-color: green'}
})
```

Seems so simple, but it eludes me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are changing the background color for a particular component I think you can simple add your class to the parent div and attach it there? If I have understood this correctly?

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I want to change the background of the site only when the login page load. I can change the css for index.html but then it applies to the entire app and not a specific page.

Comment: I too see no direct method to change the body color the way you want, I will search and let you know if I could find anything. Please post the solution if you are able to find out the solution.

Comment: please let me know if you find any problem implementing this solution(given in answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this could solve your problem. Use Renderer2 in your application login component. Initialize it in your constructor and then oninit method try to change the background image and color as given below,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

then do this,

```
constructor(public renderer: Renderer2, public elementRef: ElementRef){  }
```

now in your init method do this to change the color of your body,

```
  ngOnInit(){
    let parentElement = this.renderer.selectRootElement('.changeColor');
    parentElement.bgColor = "blue";
    const el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
    parentElement.appendChild(el);
  }
```

ensure that you put the "changeColor" class in your body tag, now when you navigate to other component try to change the bgColor back to whatever color you wanted for the rest of  your application.